# How to fully reset doctrine for performance

Tags: symfony, doctrine-orm, doctrine, batch-processing

I have a Symfony application with Doctrine.

I need to create a command that will iterate through several thousands of records from the database, retrieving related data and processing it.

As entities are loaded, doctrine becomes more and more slow - as its identity map increases - from dozens of records per second processed to barely a few records per minute.

I would expect that executing `$em->clear()` would reset doctrine and would allow my process to be more efficient but it generates the following exception when processing more results after the `clear()`.

> [Doctrine\ORM\ORMInvalidArgumentException]
>         A new entity was found through the relationship 'App\Entity\XXXX' that was not configured to cascade persist operations for entity: XXXXXX.
>
> To solve this issue: Either explicitly call EntityManager#persist() on this unknown entity or configure cascade persist this association in the mapping for example @ManyToOne(..,cascade={"persist"})

My code is something like this:

```
$qb = $repository->createQueryBuilder....;
$i = 0;
do {
    $list = $this->paginator->paginate($qb->getQuery(), $i, 10);
    foreach($list as $item){
        $this->processItem($item);
    }
    $this->em->clear();
    $i++;
} while(count($list) > 0);
```

If I try to detach just `$item` in each iteration, it works, but the related entities loaded during `processItem` are not detached, so IdentityMap keeps growing.

It is like `clear()` doesn't really clear all, or that after `clear()` not all entities are properly reloaded.

Of course, if I remove the `clear()` function the error is not fired.

Comment: Are you flushing your entities in `processItem` before clearing? You might want to read doctrine [batch processing docs](https://www.doctrine-project.org/projects/doctrine-orm/en/2.6/reference/batch-processing.html) if you haven't done that already.

Comment: @msg yes, processItem performs the flush action. And in this flush action it throws the error.

Comment: You seem to create relationships inside the `processItem` function. How exactly are those entities related?

Comment: @msg I was speed-reading and thought you recommended to batch the operations. Sorry, the link is indeed a good recommendation :)

Comment: Yes, I've readed the batch processing docs.
@NicolaiFröhlich The processItem  function reads several relations from the entities and generates new entities related with the $item. But as processItems performs the flush action, these entities are properly saved. The exception, points to an entity that was already in the database before the execution of the command, not a new one

Comment: To me it looks like you are persisting this entity that was already in the database again. So are you fetching it before and trying to persist it after the batch processing and clearing the identity-map? If yes that'd explain the error-message.

Comment: @NicolaiFröhlich thanks, after double checking the code the issue was that I was using an entity loaded before the loop, so it was removed when calling clear causing the exception.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After digging and checking twice the code, thanks to @NicolaiFröhlich, i've found the problem.

The issue indeed was that upper in my code I was loading some entities, that then after `clear()` were removed from the Identity Map, and those entities where used in the `processItem` function.